# unit testing angular component with @input

Tags: angular, unit-testing, input

I have an angular component which has an @input attribute and processes this on the `ngOnInit`.  Normally when unit testing an @input I just give it as `component.inputproperty=value` but in this case I cannot since its being used on the `ngOnInit`.  How do I provide this input value in the `.spec.ts` file.  The only option I can think of is to create a test host component, but I really don't want to go down this path if there is an easier method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doing a test host component is a way to do it but I understand it can be too much work.

The `ngOnInit` of a component gets called on the first `fixture.detectChanges()` after `TestBed.createComponent(...)`.

So to make sure it is populated in the `ngOnInit`, set it before the first `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Example:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.inputproperty = value; // set the value here
fixture.detectChanges(); // first fixture.detectChanges call after createComponent will call ngOnInit
```

I assume all of that is in a `beforeEach` and if you want different values for `inputproperty`, you have to have get creative with `describe`s and `beforeEach`.

For instance:

```
describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [BannerComponent]}).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('inputproperty is blahBlah', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
     component.inputproperty = 'blahBlah';
     fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should do xyz if inputProperty is blahBlah', () => {
     // test when inputproperty is blahBlah
   });
  });

  describe('inputproperty is abc', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
     component.inputproperty = 'abc';
     fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should do xyz if inputProperty is abc', () => {
     // test when inputproperty is abc
   });
  });
});
```