# how to test an angular component with required @Input

Tags: angular

I have a component with the following structure using [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528395/make-directive-input-required/54240378#54240378)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component[required]',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.component.scss']
})
export class Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() required!: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

And when I execute its default test I've got the error `component required at least required property` and I have already tried what is they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63839249/unit-testing-angular-component-with-input)

here is the test I am running

```
describe('ComponentComponent', () => {
  let component: ComponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ComponentComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.required = 'foo';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.required = 'foo';
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.required = 'foo';
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: "and I have already tried what is they say here", where are you initializing `required` in your test? the link you posted does that, after `fixture.componentInstance`, you would do `component.required = 'something'`

Comment: I skipped my trial doing that because the original thread already shows my point, the problem remains after doing that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unit testing angular component with @input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63839249/unit-testing-angular-component-with-input)

Comment: @possum No, It didn't, I have already tried that and didn't work, also I think the scenario is different, because is not only that I have an `Input` decorator but the fact that I have a selector that makes the property mandatory for the component.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```html
describe('ComponentComponent', () => {
  let component: ComponentComponent;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ ComponentComponent ]
    });
    component = TestBed.inject(ComponentComponent);
  });
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not definitively answer the question and from what I can tell from reading the question, does nothing to address the issue.